# React-Native - Best Way to Send App to iPhone for Testing

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, expo

I've read through the documentation and I've ejected my app. This creates the `/ios` folder I need with all of the xCode files. I opened the file with xCode.

I used an unedited bootstrapped version made using `create-react-native-app` and then immediately ran the `npm run eject` program.

When I open the files with xCode, I can properly assign the team. I go ahead and click build to send the project to my attached iPhone. It spends time building, opens the metro bundler in a terminal window, but eventually fails. It says it is missing the `main.jsbundle` file.

Does anyone have experience with this kind of workflow? Most examples show active development using `expo` or a platform specific device simulator. I would like to know how to send the application for testing on a real device quickly.

Comment: If you just want to run your app on a real phone you can use expo client without ejecting it. Testing and running means really different when you are talking about mobile apps.

Comment: I've done testing with Expo just fine on Windows and Mac, but I want to deploy the xcode files generated when it bundles. Basically getting it to run without the Expo client there.

Comment: Did you install `react-native-cli`?

Comment: react-native-cli: 2.0.1 and react-native: 0.55.4

Comment: Do you see any errors on metro bundler terminal window?

Comment: It gets to `Loading Dependency Graph... Done`, then the next line it sits and waits

Comment: How about on xcode logs?

Comment: That the main.jsbundle file doesn’t exist. It’s the o my red X error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check Your Build Configuration are you making a Release buid or debug
  build. To check got to Products > Schemes > Edit Schemes > Run
- Run this command before making a Release Build to create
  mainBundle.js

> react-native bundle --entry-file index.ios.js --platform ios --dev
>   false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios

- For debug configuration Xcode will automatically handle bundling

Comment: Ok, I'm trying this now using `react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios` I changed index.ios.js to index.js as react-native uses a universal file now. It did seem to create a bundle, I'll see if that made a difference.

Comment: That did make the bundle, and its no longer a red file in xCode. But now I'm getting the following error: `2018-06-29 22:10:42.679865-0400 starter[9718:3879453] Unhandled JS Exception: Application starter has not been registered.` I am going to bootstrap another one and see if I can get a different result. Getting closer.

Comment: I think one of the problems I was having was running it in debug mode. This requires connections to the app to be active. Once I switched over to release mode, it now builds and will open without any assistance from xcode once it is installed.

Comment: Marking this as the correct answer as it helped lead me to figuring it out.

Comment: Also, by far publishing with Expo and pushing to the AppStore using Application Loader worked best. No need to eject. This answer however solved it for an ejected application.